# Import fonts-face on styled component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I use `styled component` for library css on my ReactJS application. I want to `@font-face` but not working.

code on `GlobalStyle.js`

```
import {  createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import MaisonBook from '../assets/fonts/MaisonNeue-Book.ttf';


const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: Maison Nueue;
    src: url(${MaisonBook});
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: Maison Nueue;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/MaisonNeue-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
  }
`

export default GlobalStyle;
```

on `index.js`

```
....
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <GlobalStyle/>
    <MainRouter />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
....
```

Comment: Which bundler are you using? Webpack ?

Comment: check this out and see whether it gives you some insights

https://dev.to/alaskaa/how-to-import-a-web-font-into-your-react-app-with-styled-components-4-1dni

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "MaisonNueue";
 src: url(${require('../assets/fonts/MaisonNeue-Book.otf')}) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "MaisonNueueBold";
 src: url(${require('../assets/fonts/MaisonNeue-Bold.otf')}) format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: No explanation for how this works.

Answer (score 3):

The font name should be placed in quotation marks: `font-family: 'Maison Nueue';`

```
import {  createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import MaisonBook from '../assets/fonts/MaisonNeue-Book.ttf';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Maison Nueue';
    src: url(${MaisonBook});
  }
  h1 {
     font-family: 'Maison Nueue';
  }
`

export default GlobalStyle;
```

and

```
....
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <GlobalStyle/>
    <h1>Is it works?</h1>
    <MainRouter />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
....
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the declared font to any elements? (edited my response)