# font doesn't apply in ReactJS with Bootswatch

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, bootswatch

I tried many solutions for applying this font but it still not working.

```
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Samim';
   src: local('Samim'), url(./resources/fonts/Samim.ttf) format('truetype');
   font-weight: 900;
 }

.App {
  font-family: Samim;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

i use ***bootswatch*** for styling .
should i modify *bootstrap.min.css* or install something to solve my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import fonts-face on styled component ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076453/import-fonts-face-on-styled-component-reactjs)

Comment: I saw it but I do not use styled component and their solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In style, I use the following structure to define the font. try this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Samim;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    url('../resources/fonts/Samim.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```